# Add a value box to tab panels already containing a plot using the flexdashboard package

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I’m beginning to learn how to create dashboards using the flexdashboard package. However, I have encountered an issue to add a value box using the valueBox function. In particular, how can I add a value box above the plot in Panel 1 and Panel 2 ?
[image]

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme:
      version: 4
      bootswatch: minty
    orientation: columns
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include = FALSE}
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(flexdashboard)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)

year <- seq(2006, 2023, 1)
value <- runif(length(year), min = 0, max = 25) 


```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

**Sidebar 1**
```{r}

```

**Sidebar 2**
```{r}

```

Page 1
=======================================================================

Column {data-width=700}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### **Title 1**

```{r, fig.width = 5, fig.height= 10}
```

### **Title 2**

```{r, fig.width = 5, fig.height= 10}
```

Column {data-width=600}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### **Title 3**

```{r, fig.width = 24, fig.height= 6}

b <- flexdashboard::valueBox(1000, icon = "fa-line-chart",col="orange")

## Retrieve the plot
p <- plot(year, value)
rp <- renderPlot({p}, height = 400, width = 600, res = 50)

tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Panel 1", rp), tabPanel("Panel 2", rp))
```
````

I have tried the following code but it doesn’t work:

```
tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Panel 1", b, rp), tabPanel("Panel 2", b, rp))
```

Comment: Are you bound to using {flexdashboard}? Using basic shiny and maybe {bslib} for theming would be much simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I’m not bound to using flexdashoard. However, it seemed to me that it was possible to integrate functions from the Shiny package into a dashboard built via flexdashboard.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Do you have views on how the new [Quarto dashboards](https://quarto.org/docs/dashboards/) stack up against {flexdashboard} and the other options, both for this question specifically, or more generally for someone wanting to start building dashboards in R?

Comment: That is true, MarineRégis however, there is [no official support](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/37) for `tabPanel`s in {flexdashboard}. @Tobo please also check the above link regarding Quartos possibilities. In general I'd say using the shiny runtime for rmarkdown (or quarto) makes sense for very limited apps or if you have an existing codebase. Using basic shiny and e.g. {shinydashboardPlus} or {bs4Dash} is much more flexible. If you are interested I'll answer with an example.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, I'm interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround (see above comments - there is [no official support](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/37) for `tabPanel`s in {flexdashboard}) here is how to create a similar layout using library([bslib](https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/index.html)), which provides us with modern UI components based on Bootstrap:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(bsicons)
library(thematic)
library(datasets)

ui <- page_navbar(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 5, bootswatch = "darkly"),
  nav_spacer(),
  nav_panel(
    title = "Home",
    icon = bs_icon("house"),
    layout_sidebar(
      sidebar = sidebar("Sidebar"),
      layout_column_wrap(
        layout_column_wrap(
          width = "100%",
          card(
            card_header("A header"),
            markdown("Some text with a [link](https://github.com).")
          ),
          card(
            card_header("A header"),
            markdown("Some text with a [link](https://github.com).")
          )
        ),
        card(
          card_header("A header"),
          navset_tab(
            nav_panel(
              title = "One",
              p("First tab content."),
              layout_column_wrap(
                value_box(
                  title = "1st value",
                  value = "123",
                  showcase = bs_icon("bar-chart"),
                  theme = "purple",
                  p("The 1st detail")
                ),
                value_box(
                  title = "2nd value",
                  value = "456",
                  showcase = bs_icon("graph-up"),
                  theme = "teal",
                  p("The 2nd detail"),
                  p("The 3rd detail")
                ),
                value_box(
                  title = "3rd value",
                  value = "789",
                  showcase = bs_icon("pie-chart"),
                  theme = "pink",
                  p("The 4th detail"),
                  p("The 5th detail"),
                  p("The 6th detail")
                )
              ),
              plotOutput("plot")
            ),
            nav_panel(title = "Two", p("Second tab content.")),
            nav_panel(title = "Three", p("Third tab content"))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  nav_panel(
    title = "Empty page",
    icon = bs_icon("database"),
    tags$p('Empty page')
  ),
  title = "My App"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cat(paste("bootswatch_themes:", paste0(bootswatch_themes(), collapse = ", ")))
  thematic_shiny()
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("My Plot") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  }, res = 96L)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: result]